# Binding complex objects during form post

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a bit of functionality that I need to put on a number of pages, so I've implemented it as a partial view.

Within this partial view, I have a dropdown, an add button, and an  of "items", each of which includes a delete button.  The functionality is obvious.  Clicking on any of the delete buttons removes the associated item, selecting an item from the dropdown and clicking add adds that item.

The complexity is that this needs to happen entirely in javascript - changes to the list of items needs to happen entirely client-side, and nothing happens on the server until the form as a whole is submitted.  (That is, we don't want to update the server via ajax on every change, we want to collect the changes and submit them in toto on form submit.)

The second complexity is that this form needs to be pretty much drop-in, with as few requirements on the parent view as possible.

So I've created a viewmodel for the partial:

```
public class ItemsModel
{
    // The list to be displayed in the dropdown
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> itemsList { get; set; }
    // The list of selected items
    public List<string> items { get; set; }
    public string itemsJson
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.items); }
        set { this.items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(value);
    }

    public ItemsModel()
    {
        this.itemsList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        this.items = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

And the viewmodel for the page contains an instance of this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // Assorted stuff
    public ItemsModel itemsModel;
}
```

When the Controller builds the model, during the HttpGet, it populates the ItemsModel object with the two lists. The view for the page includes the partial, passing the itemsModel:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_itemsList", Model.itemsModel);
```

Within the partial, I construct the dropdown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("itemsList", new SelectList(Model.itemsList, "Key", "Value")
```

And I populate the  with javascript:

```
var items = $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(Model.itemsJson)');
var itemsUl = $('#itemsUl');
itemsUl.empty();
var iTemplate = $('#itemTemplate').html();
for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
{
    var template = iTemplate.nformat("{item}": items[i]);
    itemsUl.append($(template));
}
```

And that's as far as I've gotten.  My intent was to add javascript to handle the inserts and deletes, but there's no point, at this point. Because when I submit the page with the unmodified lists, MyViewModel.itemsModel is null.  Browsing around on the web, I've seen a number of posts about how MVC binds Request items to complex lists, but none of them are relevant to my problem, because nothing is getting to MVC to be bound.

I've watched in Fiddler, and the request that is being sent includes "...&itemsList=&..." - it's not sending any data at all.

So I'm wondering if I'm chasing down the wrong path, entirely.  What is the normal way for including complex data in a form submit?  I've read up on FormData(), but that seems to apply only to an Ajax-style send, it doesn't affect a normal form submit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is usual, in these sorts of problems, I just wasn't thinking things through.

If I want a value to be included in the request during a form submit, I need to put in a form element.

First, I removed the parallel json properties - it's easy enough to serialize/deserialize inline, and it makes it more obvious what is going on. So my model becomes:

```
public class ItemsModel
{
    // The list to be displayed in the <select>
    public List<string> itemsList { get; set; }

    // The list of selected items
    public List<string> items { get; set; }

    public ItemsModel()
    {
        this.itemsList = new List<string>();
        this.items = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

The  list is only sent to the browser, it doesn't need to come back, so it can be injected straight into a javascript variable:

```
var itemsSelect = $('#itemsSelect');
itemsSelect.find('option').remove();

var itemsList = 
    $.parseJSON('@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.itemsList))');

for (i = 0; i < itemsList.length; i++)
{
    var item = itemsList[i];
    itemsSelect
        .append($("<option>", { value: item })
        .text(item ? item : "Select Item"));
}
```

The items, though, need to come back. Which means that the json needs to be injected on the page as a hidden element:

```
@Html.Hidden("itemsJson", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.items))
```

And then in the javascript, we extract the data into an array:

```
var items = JSON.parse($('#itemsJson').val());
```

And then I build <li>'s from these elements, and add them to my <ul>.  The user then chooses an item from the <select> and clicks the "add" button, or clicks the "delete" button in one of the <li>'s, and I either remove an <option> from the dropdown and add a <li> to the <ul>, or I remove a <li> from the <ul> and add an <option> to the <select>. In either case, I need to reserialize the array and update the hidden element:

```
$('#itemsJson').val(JSON.stringify(items));
```

Then, when I submit the form, the browser will include a JSON string in the request, named "itemsJson". The only remaining question is how to get that into the HttpPost action.  There are three possibilities:

1. I could just extract the value from Request["itemsJson"]. I don't like that.
2. I could build a custom binding to deserialize the JSON and update the model. That seems like unnecessary work.
3. Or, I could just add another argument to my Action, and deserialize it there.

I chose option 3:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Perishable(MyViewModel model, string itemsJson)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.itemsModel= new ItemsModel
        {
            items= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(itemsJson)
        };

        ...
    }
}
```